# Should I automatically swap matrix dimensions if the passed matrices are formatted incorrectly?

Tags: c#

I'm working on making a matrix math object that's as generic as possible. I currently have done multiplication. I've run into a decision I have to make, but first, here's the code.

```
namespace MatrixMath
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Matrix is a class designed to do math on matrices for you.
    /// Matrix methods assume that the matrices are formatted as [rows, columns] or [rows][columns].
    /// </summary>
    public static class Matrix
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Multiplies two matrices together. Assumes formatting is [rows, columns]. Will automatically
        /// correct this when wrong, except when both matrices have the same number of rows and columns.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>
        /// If the return value is the answer you expect from multiplying <paramref name="secondMatrix"/> by <paramref name="firstMatrix"/>
        /// instead of what you intended, this typically means you've formatted your matrices as
        /// [columns, rows]. The following code example should fix your issue.
        /// 
        /// Matrix.Multiply(Matrix.SwapDimensions(secondMatrix), Matrix.SwapDimensions(firstMatrix));
        /// </example>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The datatype the matrices are. If it's a non numeric datatype, an <see cref="ArgumentException"/> will be thrown.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="firstMatrix">The first matrix to multiply.</param>
        /// <param name="secondMatrix">The second matrix to multiply.</param>
        /// <returns>The product of the two matrices.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"></exception>
        public static T[,] Multiply<T>(T[,] firstMatrix, T[,] secondMatrix)
        {
            if (firstMatrix is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstMatrix));
            if (secondMatrix is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(secondMatrix));

            if (!TypeIsNumber<T>())
                throw new ArgumentException($"{typeof(T)} is a data type that can't be multiplied.");

            int firstMatrixRowCount = firstMatrix.GetLength(0);
            int firstMatrixColumnCount = firstMatrix.GetLength(1);
            int secondMatrixRowCount = secondMatrix.GetLength(0);
            int secondMatrixColumnCount = secondMatrix.GetLength(1);

            if (firstMatrixColumnCount != secondMatrixRowCount)
            {
                if (firstMatrixRowCount == secondMatrixColumnCount)
                {
                    return SwapDimensions(Multiply(SwapDimensions(secondMatrix), SwapDimensions(firstMatrix)));
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Matrix size mismatch. First matrix columns {firstMatrixColumnCount}, second matrix rows {secondMatrixRowCount}.");
            }

            T[,] resultMatrix = new T[firstMatrixRowCount, secondMatrixColumnCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < firstMatrixRowCount; i++)
            {
                T[] firstMatrixRow = GetColumn(firstMatrix, i);

                for (int j = 0; j < secondMatrixColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    T[] secondMatrixColumn = GetRow(secondMatrix, j);

                    resultMatrix[i, j] = Multiply(firstMatrixRow, secondMatrixColumn);
                }
            }

            return resultMatrix;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Multiplies two matrices together. Assumes formatting is [rows][columns]. Will automatically
        /// correct this when wrong, except when both matrices have the same number of rows and columns.
        /// </summary>
        /// /// <example>
        /// If the return value is the answer you expect from multiplying <paramref name="secondMatrix"/> by <paramref name="firstMatrix"/>
        /// instead of what you intended, this typically means you've formatted your matrices as
        /// [columns][rows]. The following code example should fix your issue.
        /// 
        /// Matrix.Multiply(Matrix.SwapDimensions(secondMatrix), Matrix.SwapDimensions(firstMatrix));
        /// </example>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The datatype the matrices are. If it's a non numeric datatype, an <see cref="ArgumentException"/> will be thrown.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="firstMatrix">The first matrix to multiply.</param>
        /// <param name="secondMatrix">The second matrix to multiply.</param>
        /// <returns>The product of the two matrices.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"></exception>
        public static T[][] Multiply<T>(T[][] firstMatrix, T[][] secondMatrix)
        {
            // Convert firstMatrix to a matrix of type T[,]
            T[,] convertedFirstMatrix = ConvertToTwoDimensionalArray(firstMatrix);
            T[,] convertedSecondMatrix = ConvertToTwoDimensionalArray(secondMatrix);
            T[,] convertedResultMatrix = Multiply(convertedFirstMatrix, convertedSecondMatrix);

            return ConvertToArrayOfArrays(convertedResultMatrix);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Multiplies a matrix by a given multiplier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The datatype the matrices are. If <typeparamref name="T"/>'s a non numeric datatype, an <see cref="ArgumentException"/> will be thrown.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="matrix">The matrix to multiply.</param>
        /// <param name="multiplier">The numeric value the matrix will be multiplied by.</param>
        /// <returns>The product of the matrix and the multiplier.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
        public static T[,] Multiply<T>(T[,] matrix, T multiplier)
        {
            if (matrix is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(matrix));
            if (multiplier is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(multiplier));

            if (!TypeIsNumber<T>())
                throw new ArgumentException($"{typeof(T)} is a data type that can't be multiplied.");

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0;j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] *= (dynamic)multiplier;
                }
            }

            return matrix;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="matrix"></param>
        /// <param name="multiplier"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T[][] Multiply<T>(T[][] matrix, T multiplier) => ConvertToArrayOfArrays(Multiply(ConvertToTwoDimensionalArray(matrix), multiplier));

        /// <summary>
        /// Swaps the rows and columns of the passed matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The data type of the matrix.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="matrix">The matrix you want to swap the dimensions of.</param>
        /// <returns>A copy of the matrix with the dimensions swapped.</returns>
        public static T[,] SwapDimensions<T>(T[,] matrix)
        {
            int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
            int columns = matrix.GetLength(1);

            T[,] swappedMatrix = new T[columns, rows];

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    swappedMatrix[j, i] = matrix[i, j];
                }
            }

            return swappedMatrix;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Swaps the rows and columns of the passed matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The data type of the matrix.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="matrix">The matrix you want to swap the dimensions of.</param>
        /// <returns>A copy of the matrix with the dimensions swapped.</returns>
        public static T[][] SwapDimensions<T>(T[][] matrix) => ConvertToArrayOfArrays(SwapDimensions(ConvertToTwoDimensionalArray(matrix)));

        private static T[,] ConvertToTwoDimensionalArray<T>(T[][] matrix)
        {
            T[,] result = new T[matrix.Length, matrix[0].Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].Length; j++)
                {
                    result[i,j] = matrix[i][j];
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static T[][] ConvertToArrayOfArrays<T>(T[,] matrix)
        {
            T[][] result = new T[matrix.GetLength(0)][];

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                result[i] = new T[matrix.GetLength(1)];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    result[i][j] = matrix[i, j];
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static T Multiply<T>(T[] firstMatrix, T[] secondMatrix)
        {
            if (firstMatrix.Length != secondMatrix.Length)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Matrix size mismatch. First matrix columns {firstMatrix.Length}, second matrix rows {secondMatrix.Length}.");

            dynamic sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < firstMatrix.Length; i++)
            {
                dynamic? itemOne = firstMatrix[i];
                dynamic? itemTwo = secondMatrix[i];

                sum += (T)(itemOne * itemTwo);
            }

            return (T)sum;
        }

        private static T[] GetRow<T>(T[,] matrix, int rowNumber)
        {
            var length = matrix.GetLength(0);
            var resultMatrix = new T[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                resultMatrix[i] = matrix[i, rowNumber];
            }

            return resultMatrix;
        }

        private static T[] GetColumn<T>(T[,] matrix, int columnNumber)
        {
            var length = matrix.GetLength(1);
            var resultMatrix = new T[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                resultMatrix[i] = matrix[columnNumber, i];
            }

            return resultMatrix;
        }

        private static bool TypeIsNumber<T>()
        {
            T? foo = default;

            if (foo is null)
                return false;

            try
            {
                T bar = (T)((dynamic)foo * foo);

                if (bar.Equals(foo))
                    return true;

                return false;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my dilemma. I would like to make this as robust as possible, and as part of that, I originally decided to automatically swap the dimensions of the matrices if they aren't formatted in the way the code expects them to be ([rows, columns]).

This works in most situations because the rows and columns are tpically not the same size, so unless the matrix's number of rows is equal to the number of columns, the code will work as intended. But if they are equal for both matrices, the method will return the wrong answer. I'm not looking to fix the issue so it magically knows to swap it anyways. I don't even know if that's possible. Instead I can just leave documentation that shows how to fix it (I already have that in the XML).

Finally, the point. Is this decision a bad practice? Should I just let it run as is, and if there is an issue, leave it up to the user to fix it? If you were using the library without context, what would you expect?

I also have a few additional questions, but these are secondary to the main point.

- Is there a cleaner way to have these methods work for more than just one data type? Currently I just let the user define the type, but to do multiplication, I have to cast to dynamic. I feel like there's a better way to do that but I don't know what it is.
- Aside from all of the type casting, are there any glaring inefficiencies that I should fix? I can't find any myself, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m glad you’re asking / exploring the question.

Is auto-magically (silently) “fixing” the input a bad practice?

Yes.

Why is that?
It’s much nicer to alert the caller to a code defect, a contract violation, with informative diagnostic than to conceal the latent bug and sometimes give wrong answer without warning.

When caller gets fatal diagnostic, the source code will soon be improved with a helpful edit, so it is good to “fail hard”.
Otherwise, the source is much less likely to be improved.